# The order of permutation groups and alternating groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

The question was:

> True or False: $\forall{n}\in{\mathbb{N}}$ the group $S_n$ and $A_n$ have different sizes.

My answer is False. That is since  both $A_1 =(\text{id})$ and $S_1 =(\text{id})$.

Can any one confirm my answer please? Thank you very much.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Of course $S_n$ in general is much larger than $A_n$. $A_n$  is the group of permutations with even parity only, while $S_n$ is the group of all permutations of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$. Not all permutations are of even parity, e.g., consider
$$(1,2)\circ(1,3)\circ(1,5)$$
the product of three transpositions that give rise to a cycle. In fact any cycle of odd length does not belong to $A_n$.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question